# HOBt and DCC in the synthesis of peptides

Tags: organic-chemistry

DCC is a well known reagent used for the synthesis of peptides, aiding the formation of the amide bond by forming an intermediate with the carboxylic acid that contains a leaving group. During my research on the reagent HOBt, or hydroxybenzotriazole, I came across a scheme which showed DCC and HOBt being used in conjunction as a method for peptide synthesis (picture shown below). What is the point of the HOBt being used here? Doesn't the intermediate formed by the DCC molecule already contain a sufficient leaving group?

[image]

Comment: HOBt is a good nucleophile and the HOBt ester is a better leaving group than the DCC adduct. This simply gives better yields than using DCC alone